# Svd recomposition with Mathnet numerics library seems wrong

Tags: c#, svd, regression-testing, math.net

I'm looking for non regression between Mathnet.Iridium and Mathnet.Numerics. Here is my code, using Mathnet.Numerics :

```
double[][] symJaggedArray = new double[5][];
symJaggedArray[0] = new double[] { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
symJaggedArray[1] = new double[] { 0, 2, 4, 0, 0 };
symJaggedArray[2] = new double[] { 0, 4, 5, -4, 5 };
symJaggedArray[3] = new double[] { 0, 0, -4, -8, 12 };
symJaggedArray[4] = new double[] { 0, 0, 5, 12, -5 };
symDenseMatrix = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new Matrix(symJaggedArray).CopyToArray());// not optimal but it's not the point

Svd svd = new UserSvd(symDenseMatrix , true);
Matrix<double> recompo = svd.U().Multiply(svd.W()).Multiply(svd.VT());
```

When i compare recompo and the initial matrix, they are different.
I found this difference when comparing each decomposition matrix with the previous implementation :

- U and singularValueDecomposition.LeftSingularVectors are equal
- W and singularValueDecomposition.S are equal
- VT and Matrix.Transpose(singulaValueDecomposition.RightSingularVectors) are different

Finally, recomposition with older API is correct.

MathNet.Numerics version used : Math.NET Numerics v2.5.0

So my question is : Where is my mistake when rebuilding initial matrix with the new API ?

RecompoMatrix =

- 3 0 0 0 0
- 0 -1.216846655456 2.83903817786199 1.4472680220698 2.89215520227421
- 0 -2.46695399700557 8.657344064164 0.92863757484644 -0.31963101527516
- 0 0.349540484418384 8.20515629935223 -2.26741625715781 -12.3049605878983
- 0 -0.402667067831389 -6.32914150795323 9.13315298351198 8.3884053064068

Comment: I had a similar problem with MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization.Svd(Of Double) trying to find a plane's Normal. After reading https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810048/plane-fitting-using-svd-normal-vector, I resolved it by transposing my input points (X,Y,Z) from N,3 to 3,N and taking the answer from U(3) rather than V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly tried to reproduce this, but I failed. I've used Math.NET Numerics v2.6 (NuGet package), but there was no change around the SVD decomposition in this release. This is my code:

```
var m = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
   { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 2, 4, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 4, 5, -4, 5 },
   { 0, 0, -4, -8, 12},
   { 0, 0, 5, 12, -5 }});

var svd = m.Svd(true);
//var svd = new UserSvd(m, true);

svd.U() * svd.W() * svd.VT()
```

Where the last line evaluates to:

```
DenseMatrix 5x5-Double
           3            0            0            0            0
           0            2            4 -1.23512E-15   -3.747E-16
           0            4            5           -4            5
           0  3.26128E-16           -4           -8           12
           0 -1.15186E-15            5           12           -5
```

VT in this case is:

```
DenseMatrix 5x5-Double
           0   -0.0449147     0.249507     0.718099    -0.648123
           0     0.466822     0.823535    0.0324572     0.320646
           0     0.208479     0.176729    -0.670706    -0.689534
          -1            0            0            0            0
           0     0.858252    -0.477811     0.182848   -0.0408292
```

I wonder why you get a completely different result?
Can you try again with the same code I posted above?

Comment: You get an interesting point : 
It gets the correct same result with your method m.Svd(true) but it is incorrect if you substitute :
//var svd = m.Svd(true);
var svd = new UserSvd(m, true);

Comment: Anyway, i mark your answer because it saved my regression. Thanks a lot for this. I'm going to use Matrix.Svd(). Nevertheless, i really think there is either a problem in UserSvd and DenseSvd or i didn't understand how it has to be used.

Comment: Thanks!

I actually get exactly the same result with both DenseSvd and UserSvd when I try out both methods (in LINQPad). So I'm still interested to find out what the issue is, to make sure there is no bug hidden somewhere.

Comment: Which additional information would you like ? The only substitution i'm doing is changing m.Svd(true) with  new UserSvd(m, true). 
In order to help you , i've made a quick diff between my UserSvd and http://code.google.com/p/mathnet-numerics/source/browse/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Complex32/Factorization/UserSvd.cs?spec=svnd0b93b247a09623f12fae596451ce99c3aeca25f&r=6f122ed0b69411eefa0fd2413188ecccc6943b19 and it's seems that the only difference is that i'm using double and line 403 ->   if (ztest.AlmostEqualInDecimalPlaces(test, 15)) versus       if (ztest.AlmostEqualInDecimalPlaces(test, 7))

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered centering the matrices before SVD? It might have been centered before computation of Eigen vectors.