# Is SVD included in MathNet.Numerics x86?

Tags: c#, svd, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I need to calculate the Singular Value Decomposition of a Dense matrix but it doesn't seem to be included in the package I'm using: `MathNet.Numerics x86 v2.4.0.26` downloaded from Nuget package manager.

I am referencing this question [Svd recomposition..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100873/svd-recomposition-with-mathnet-numerics-library-seems-wrong)

The syntax included in the answer linked is:

```
 var m = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
   { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 2, 4, 0, 0 },
   { 0, 4, 5, -4, 5 },
   { 0, 0, -4, -8, 12},
   { 0, 0, 5, 12, -5 }});


  var svd = m.Svd(true);  //The method Svd() doesn't seem to be available in v2.4 

  svd.U() * svd.W() * svd.VT()
```

Nor is  [`svd()`](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/DenseMatrix.htm) listed in the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single/DenseMatrix.htm).

I'm looking for a simple example of generating a SVD of a DenseMatrix using the MathNet.Numerics x86 library.

Unfortunately the method `inverse()` is just returning NaN so I'm hoping to approximate the inverse using singular value decomposition.

Comment: Of course, it's generally best not to form the inverse of a matrix

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am trying to use the [Covariance Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) and to use it in a multivariate Gaussian distribution I thought the inverse must be found.  So I'm approximating it using a [Moore-Penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).  Is there a better way?

Comment: It's generally best to avoid writing down the inverse matrix. That tends to lack robustness.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is barely coherent.  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You generally want to find A^-1*x rather than A^-1 itself and you can find the former more efficiently by doing so directly than by writing out the inverse and then pre-multiplying.

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation I found classes for singular value decomposition

`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.` *`Double/Single/Generic`* `.Factorization.Svd` are abstract classes.

`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.` *`Double/Single/Generic`* `.Factorization.DenseSvd` are implementations.  Pass your matrix to the constructor, the results are available via members.

Comment: Yeah I found that as well but I'm not sure how to implement that.  When I tried to construct an object with it no luck (abstract class) and there are no static methods included other than `equals`.

Comment: Hmm, it looks as if the `Solve` method *ought* to be static.  The documentation isn't very good, IMO.  Have you tried the `DenseSvd` class?  It has a constructor.

Comment: You got it! that's it.  DenseSvd is exactly what I need.  Add that to your answer and I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Svd() used to be an extension method in v2, which unfortunately is only available if you include the [right namespace](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/ExtensionMethods.htm). In your case, adding the following line should do the trick:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
```

This is one of the areas that have been greatly simplified in the upcoming v3 release, where this is a proper method. I suggest you have a look at one of the recent v3 packages (as of writing this e.g. the [v3.0.0-alpha7](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/3.0.0-alpha7)).

Comment: I was able to get the DenseSvd to work fairly easily, and I tried adding that specific namespace and it worked as well.  Thanks!